# How to filter GCP stackdriver logs by timestamp from python for given Date range

Tags: python, logging, filter, google-cloud-logging

FILTER = ' timestamp > "2021-04-15T01:00:00Z" AND timestamp < "2021-04-20T01:00:00Z" '

this filter wonn't work for given date range,
what can be the possible FILTER in python that can fetch logs within the given datetime range

Comment: What is the current result? Are you seeing logs for both given times or an error?

Comment: Using the above filter I don't get any logs even they exist.

Answer (score 3):

Instead
FILTER = ' timestamp > "2021-04-15T01:00:00Z" AND timestamp < "2021-04-20T01:00:00Z

I simply removed "AND" keyword and it worked for me in python.

FILTER = ' timestamp > "2021-04-15T01:00:00Z" timestamp < "2021-04-20T01:00:00Z